# Unable to delete files from locked S3 glacier vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have locked a S3 glacier vault based on the example given here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-lock-policy.html

(I'm using the first example to lock the vault for 7 days as follows):

```
{
     "Version":"2012-10-17",
     "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid": "deny-based-on-archive-age",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Action": "glacier:DeleteArchive",
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:glacier:us-west-2:123456789012:vaults/examplevault"
         ],
         "Condition": {
             "NumericLessThan" : {
                  "glacier:ArchiveAgeInDays" : "7"
             }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

However when trying to delete the archive in the vault even after 7 days, I'm getting an error as below (I'm using fast glacier):

```
Task failed - AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:root is not authorized to perform: glacier:DeleteArchive on resource: arn:aws:glacier:ap-southeast-2:xxxx:vaults/test with an explicit deny TaskID: 673
```

Seems very strange because using the same access, I can create and delete archives in other vaults and delete vaults itself after the inventory has been updated

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems strange. I presume your IAM User has `glacier:DeleteArchive` permissions, and it is only being impact by the Vault Lock policy? Maybe wait an extra day to be sure it isn't within 7 days? Hopefully we don't need to provide a `ArchiveAgeInDays` condition with the call.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - The IAM user is actually root (Access Key/ID via My Security Credentials), so has all the permissions